# Can my Date Picker Print my date picked on the EditText not on Toast?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have this code where when I picked a date it only shows on toast, is there any way for it to be inserted in my EditText? Here is my code.

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etFirstname, etMiddlename, etLastname, etBirthDate, etAddress, etUsername, etPassword;
Spinner spRole;
int year_x,month_x,day_x;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    showDialogOnButtonClick();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void showDialogOnButtonClick(){
    etBirthDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBirthDate);

    etBirthDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  if(id == DIALOG_ID) {
      return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);
  }
      return null;
  }
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpListener
    = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    year_x = year;
    month_x = monthOfYear;
    day_x = dayOfMonth;
    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, year_x + "/" +  month_x + "/" + day_x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
};
}
```

And yes I set my EditText clickable to show the datepicker lol. Can i instert the date picked where I can also click on my EditText? Thank you for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the toast :

`Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, year_x + "/" +  month_x + "/" + day_x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

then set date in edittext :

`etBirthDate.setText(year_x + "/" +  month_x + "/" + day_x);`

Comment: Thanks sir! I really appreciate! :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    year_x = year;
    month_x = monthOfYear;
    day_x = dayOfMonth;
    etBirthDate.setText(year_x + "/" +  month_x + "/" + day_x);
}
};
```